# What is the probability that all three positions are filled by girls?

Tags: probability

13) Allie, Bert, Cami, Dan, Emily, Fred, Gustav, and Heidi are all part of a club. They need to select a president, a vice-president, and a treasurer. What is the probability that all three positions are filled by girls (Allie, Cami, Emily, or Heidi)?

I'm providing a solution below. Just want to know if I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

This is picking without replacement.  Probability for a female president and a female v.p, and a female treasurer.

probability for a female president $= 4/8$

probability for a female v.p. $= 3/7$

probability for a female treasurer $= 2/6$

total probability $= \frac{4}{8} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{6}$

answer $= 1/14$

I hope I got it right.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  If you are not sure you answered the question correctly, you should put your attempt in the question itself rather than the answers.  That said, your final answer is correct.

Comment: Your final solution is correct but poorly written. For instance I read in your answer "probability for female v.p. =3/7". That is not true because that probability equals $4/8$. What you should have said is: "probability for female v.p. under condition that a female is chosen for president =3/7".

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.